# Keys from multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think is difficult to explain.

I will need the id of this array be the same for all, it has to be "url"

I have the following code:

```
$slug_sections[] = array(
        'url' => array(
            'loc' => 'products'
        )
);
$slug_sections[] = array(
        'url' => array(
            'loc' =>'home'
        )
    );
```

And the output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [url] => Array
            (
                [loc] => productos
            )

    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [url] => Array
            (
                [loc] => home
            )

    )
 )
```

I need the output has to be:

```
Array
(
[url] => Array
      (
         [loc] => productos
      )
[url] => Array
      (
         [loc] => home
       )
)
```

Some ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have more than one key of the same name as in your example there are two `url` keys.

Comment: You can't have the same key more than once.
That's just not possible.

Comment: How can two different arrays be present in same index? That's not possible.

Comment: I know that's not possible, but maybe if I get only the value without the keys, without [0], [1]...

Comment: elements in php array always have key, either index or string

Answer (score 0):

You're using an associative array and I believe you probably want to use an indexed array. You want something like the following (it's not entirely clear what you're end goal is, so you may need to modify this a bit):

```
$slug_sections['url'][] = 'products';
$slug_sections['url'][] = 'home';
```

Doing `print_r($slug_sections);` will then give you the following output:

```
Array
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => products
            [1] => home
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$slug_url_pair['url'] = array_column($slug_sections, 'url');
```

If you are using php < 5.5.0 you cannot use array_column. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php